# Markov's inequality results negative

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-process

> $X$ is the midterm grade (out of $100$ points) of a randomly chosen student. If the
> average grade is $40$ points, find an upper bound on $Pr[X < 10]$ using Markov's
> inequality. (Hint: You may need to define a new non-negative random variable.)

I encountered this question and applied Markov's inequality but it gave me
$P(X < 10)>= 1-\left(\frac{40}{10}\right)$ and that gives us a negative bound. How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: How did you get $P(X < 10) \boxed{=} 1 - \frac{40}{10}$? The Markov inequality should have a $\leq$ sign, right? Please state the Markov inequality you know. Even if you have applied it , it has been applied wrong! Also, to apply it properly, use the variable $100-X$.

Comment: I think the markov's inequality is P(X>=a) <= (E[X]/a) and i substracted from two sides 1 get the P(X<a) >= 1-(E[X]/a) . And sorry i wrote "=" instead ">=". I edited the question.@астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: The problem is that the basic form of Markov's inequality is $P(Z \le a) \le \frac {E[Z]}{a}$ for a non-negative random variable $Z$ is only useful for $a \gt E[Z]$.  Your application should have got $P(X \ge 10) \le 4$ and so $P(X \lt 10) \ge -3$ which is true but unhelpful since all probabilities are at least $0$.  Instead use @astonvillaolofmellberg's hint of considering $Z=100-X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $P( X \leq 10) $ is not of the form desired by the Markov inequality, and using $P(X \leq 10) = 1- P(X \geq 10)$ followed by Markov does not help since the RHS becomes negative, so the inequality is obvious.

To get it to the Markov form, you must get a non-negative random variable $X'$ and a quantity $T > 0$ so that $P(X' \geq T) = P(X \leq 10)$. Then you can apply Markov inequality to $X'$ to conclude.

In this case, for example take $X' = 100-X$, then $E[X'] = 100-E[X]$ and $P(X' \geq 90) = P(X \leq 10)$. Use Markov inequality, conclude.

Comment: Is there any point for taking X′=100-X or can i apply any value that i want?

Comment: It is the easiest one to see. Other candidates for $X'$, I think it is difficult to find any other $X'$ for which you can both compute $E[X']$ and find explicit $T$ for which $P(X' \geq T) = P(X \leq 10)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think, what you did was: 
Let $X$ be the grade of a randomly chosen student. We know $0\leq X \leq 100$ and $\mathbb{E}X=40$. We have
$$\mathbb{P}(X<10)=1-\mathbb{P}(X\geq10)\geq 1-\frac{\mathbb{E}X}{10}=1-\frac{40}{10}=-3,$$
which is correct, but a completely useless lower bound.

The hint was to define a new nonnegative random variable. So, let us consider $Y:=100-X$, i..e, the points missing for full points. Then,
$$\mathbb{P}(X<10)=\mathbb{P}(100-X> 90)= \mathbb{P}(Y\geq 91)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}Y}{91}=\frac{100-\mathbb{E}X}{91}=\frac{60}{91},$$ 
which is a more useful upper bound.

Comment: I wonder that we increased the Y value 1 and get 91 so if we do not icrease and get 60/90. is it still correct?

Comment: Yes. Since $\frac{60}{91}<\frac{60}{90}=\frac{2}{3}$, it is still an upper bound for $\mathbb{P}(X<10)$. Or if you start with $\mathbb{P}(X\leq10)$, the Markov inequality gives you $\frac{2}{3}$ as an upper bound.

Comment: Thanks for answer.